# Convert spaces to tabs on only one line

Tags: whitespace, tab

So I know that, in Vim, I can use the `:retab` command to convert an entire file from multiple-spaces to tabs or from tabs to spaces, depending on the value of `:set expandtab`.

But is there a way that I can convert spaces to tabs on a single line?

My old editor, [Vile](https://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html) , has `^A-space` and `^A-tab` to do this line-by-line.  But I cannot find the matching command in Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `retab` command accepts a range.

To convert spaces into tab in the current line (providing that the `expandtab` is set to no `:set noet`) you could do:

```
:.retab!
```

To convert spaces into tab on line `42` you could do:

```
:42retab!
```

More information with [:help retab](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Aretab)

You could get your key command back with the following mappings:

```
nnoremap <C-a><tab> <cmd>set noet<bar>.retab!<cr>
nnoremap <C-a><space> <cmd>set et<bar>.retab<cr>

vnoremap <C-a><tab> :<C-u>set noet<bar>'<,'>retab!<cr>
vnoremap <C-a><space> :<C-u>set et<bar>'<,'>retab<cr>
```

Remark: Be aware that with this mapping the <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd> that increments the next integer will hold `timoutlen` before triggering.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.  I'm still getting used to vim.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: Another remark: the mappings will change the `expandtab` option as a side effect. All the lines formatted afterwards will be the same. If that's what you wanted anyway, it's perfect. If not, it may be surprising.